# Java Compilation Output in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to send someone a file with the compilation warnings and errors from a Java project I have in Eclipse, but I do not know how to do this.

I know Eclipse uses it's own Java compiler. Is there a way, for instance, to export the information in the Problems tab to a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click > Select All > Copy & Paste.

When you paste, you'll get a string of text like this...

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The import android.app.Activity is never used   GetPhotos.java  /PhotoUp/src/com/photoup    line 10 Java Problem
The import android.os.Bundle is never used  GetPhotos.java  /PhotoUp/src/com/photoup    line 15 Java Problem
```

Comment: Thank you, this is of some help, although not exactly what I need.

I've created a project in NetBeans with the same sources, executed "Clean and Build", and the information that appears in the output windows is what I need.

Is there a way to have this kind of "javac" output from Eclipse?